# How to clear E1000 network card interrupt

Tags: linux, interrupt, osdev

I'm trying to make E1000 generate an interrupt when a packet is received,

```cpp
 // enable Receiver Timer Interrupt
 reg_IMS = (uint32_t *) (base + E1000_IMS); 
 *reg_IMS = E1000_IMS_RXT0;
```

Unfortunately, the interrupt occurs only once. My guess is interrupt wasn't cleared. According to [the manual](https:///pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/readings/hardware/8254x_GBe_SDM.pdf),

> Interrupt Cause Read Register ICR (000C0H; R)
>
> All register bits are cleared upon read. As a result, reading this
>   register implicitly acknowledges any pending interrupt events.

and the comment of [some code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kohler/click/master/drivers/e1000-4.x/src/e1000_hw.c), reading ICR (Interrupt Cause Read Register) would clear the interrupt,

```cpp
/* Clear any pending interrupt events. */
icr = E1000_READ_REG(hw, ICR);
```

but this didn't work. Here are the relevant messages (`E1000_DEBUG=TX,TXERR,RX,RXERR,RXFILTER,interrupt`),

```
e1000: tx disabled
e1000: set_ics 2, ICR 0, IMR 0
e1000: set_ics 0, ICR 2, IMR 80
e1000: set_ics 80, ICR 2, IMR 80
e1000: RCTL: 127, mac_reg[RCTL] = 0x84008002
e1000: set_ics 80, ICR 82, IMR 80
e1000: ICR read: 82
ICR=82
e1000: ICR read: 0
ICR=0
e1000: set_ics 0, ICR 0, IMR 80
...
e1000: set_ics 80, ICR 0, IMR 80
e1000: set_ics 3, ICR 80, IMR 80
ns: 52:54:00:12:34:56 bound to static IP 10.0.2.15
NS: TCP/IP initialized.
opened socket
trying to bind
bound
```

which showed my nework card interrupt handler did read ICR (ICR=82 and ICR=0 was printed by the handler) for the first time. For there is no interrupt for later "set_ics 80, ICR 0".

Does anyone know how to clear/acknowledge the interrupt? Actually this is part of [Project 6 of MIT 6.828](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/labs/lab6/).

Thank you!

Comment: Did you call `lapic_eoi` in your interrupt handler?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes. I called `lapic_eoi` in the interrupt handler. I edited my question to include the log by QEMU.